# each a local and national landmark - no "is"?

Tags: grammar

Example with [a context](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canada%27s_grand_railway_hotels) (Wikipedia article):

> Canada's railway hotels are a series of grand hotels across the country, **each a local and national landmark**, and most of which are icons of Canadian history and architecture.

Why do you think there's no *is* between *each* and *a local and national landmark*?

Comment: I'm looking forward to seeing how this gets explained. All I'll say here is that it's a valid construction in English, and not too uncommon.

Comment: Note that inserting _is_ makes the second phrase an independent sentence, connected awkwardly to the first by just a comma. It could do with _and_, but the third part of the sentence would not connect in any understandable way to the rest anymore. Try inserting _each of which is_, like it was done in the third part of the sentence, and everything works fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it had the word "is", it'd be a fairly typical clause you're very familiar with:

> Each is a local and national landmark ([Pronoun] [Verb] [Adjectives] [Noun])

But without "is", it's a [verbless clause:](http://grammar.about.com/od/tz/g/verblessclauseterm.htm)

> Each a local and national landmark ([Pronoun] [Adjectives] [Noun])

Verbless clauses are used when we want to add additional information to the main clause. We've established railway hotels are a series of grand hotels, and we also want to add that they're local and national landmarks. If I wanted to add completely unconnected information, I'd need to use a verb:

> Canada's railway hotels are a series of grand hotels across the country, each one populated by train enthusiasts, and most of which are icons of Canadian history and architecture.

The main clause describes the grand hotels, but in the subordinate clause I'm describing something else: Who lives in the hotels, so it can't be a verbless clause. However, if I *were* talking about who lives in the hotels within the main clause, I could make the subordinate clause verbless again:

> Canada's railway hotels are populate by old men, each with a great love for trains, and most of the stations are icons of Canadian history and architecture.

I can make this a verbless clause because in both clauses I'm talking about the residents of the hotel. Note: I've had to clarify that the stations are icons of Canadian history later in the sentence, not the old men.

Answer (score 1):

If it was a separate sentence, yes, it would need a verb such as "is".

But it's not a separate sentence. It's a subordinate clause. That is, it's a phrase acting as an adjective modifying the word "hotels".

Let's take a somewhat simpler sentence: "The Foobar Hotel is an icon of Canadian history." Now suppose I want to add the idea that this hotel is a national landmark. I can say, "The Foobar hotel, a national landmark, is an icon of Canadian history." "A national landmark" acts as an adjective modifying "Foobar hotel". Note that such a phrase not need to be -- in fact normally is not -- a complete sentence. It's just a few words to describe the word that it modifies.

But in the actual sentence, "hotels" is plural. It is not one national landmark: it is many. The writer could have said, "Canadian railways hotels, national landmarks, are icons of Canadian history." But apparently he wanted to emphasize that they are not one big landmark, but that each one is its own landmark. So he writes, "... each a national landmark ..."

The phrase "each a ..." is a fairly common one in English for exactly this purpose.

Frankly I'm not sure what all the rules are for what constitutes a "legal" phrase in such a case.